# how do i get data from local storage in created hook using vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

this how i set the data in methods

```
  this.searchResul = response.data.Response.Results.FareBreakdown;
        localStorage.setItem("searchResult", JSON.stringify(this.searchResul));
```

but i notice that immediately i go to the route it takes about 5 seconds before my storage updates which make the created hook not getting the updated data in my storage, please is there a way i can make the storage store the data immediately after its been clicked

please this in my created hook which im trying to get the data immediately i enter the route

```
      const searchResultString = localStorage.getItem("searchResult");
      if (searchResultString) {
        this.searchResult = JSON.parse(searchResultString);
```

please how can i go about this

Comment: `localStorage.setItem()` is just as fast or slow as the rest of the (synchronous) JavaScript executing on your machine.  There is no magic that can make it faster.  If anything is somehow delaying it, it's something else in your code.

Comment: Search results typically get outdated, so you usually don't want to store them in local storage. Do you really want to persist a search between tabs and sessions, or are you abusing  the storage to transfer data between components? If so, have a look at [provide/inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html), it should serve you better.